# C++: Attemping to use std::rotate with fftw_complex data yields error: "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer"

Tags: c++, fft, fftw

I am trying to understand how to utilize the fft to process data I capture with a software defined radio. I discovered C++'s fftw3 library and attempted to look up some documentation or tutorials, and found there wasn't a whole ton to go off of.

I did however find this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kLUlutlxgQ). The code to do the fft/ifft/etc. compiles and works just fine for me, but when I attempted to implement the fftShift function I get the following compiler error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:62,
                 from CppFFTW.cpp:13:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::_V2::__rotate(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = double (*)[2]]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:1449:27:   required from ‘_FIter std::_V2::rotate(_FIter, _FIter, _FIter) [with _FIter = double (*)[2]]’
CppFFTW.cpp:76:54:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:1371:16: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
 1371 |     _ValueType __t = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__p);
      |                ^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:1373:22: error: invalid array assignment
 1373 |     *(__p + __n - 1) = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__t);
      |                      ^
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:1394:16: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
 1394 |     _ValueType __t = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__p + __n - 1));
      |                ^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:1396:10: error: invalid array assignment
 1396 |     *__p = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__t);
      |          ^
```

Here is the line I use to compile the code: `g++ CppFFTW.cpp -lfftw3 -lm`
Output for g++ --version:
'g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0'

This error message didn't make much sense to me, but I figured it meant that algorithm's std::rotate function didn't play nice with the [fftw_complex](http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html) data type anymore for some reason.

This left me with a few questions

1. How come this method worked in the tutorial video, but not for me?
2. What are some ways to go about understanding what this error message means?
3. How can I implement a working fftShift function?
4. Is there a different compiler version I should be using?

What fftShift is supposed to do is shift the zero-components to the center like in this example

```
When # elements odd:
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g} -> {e, f, g, a, b, c, d}
```

```
When # elements even:
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} -> {e, f, g, h, a, b, c, d}
```

Here is the fftShift definition definition:
Edit: The original (broken) fftShift

```
// FFT shift for complex data 
void fftShift(fftw_complex *data)
{
    // even number of elements
    if (N % 2 == 0) {
        std::rotate(&data[0], &data[N >> 1], &data[N]);
    }
    // odd number of elements
    else {
        std::rotate(&data[0], &data[(N >> 1) + 1], &data[N]);
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the code (functions/calls not relevant to the question were omitted):
Edit: Added #include  and fixed fftShift functions as per Ted's contribution.

```
* 
 Example code for how to utilize the FFTW libs
 Adapted from damian-dz C++ Tutorial
 https://github.com/damian-dz/CppFFTW/tree/master/CppFFTW
 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geYbCA137PU&t=0s)
 To compile, run: g++ CppFFTW.cpp -lfftw3 -lm
 -lfftw3 -lm links the code to the fftw3 library
*/

#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <complex> // Added post feedback from Ted

// macros for real & imaginary parts
#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1

// length of the complex arrays
#define N 8

/* Computres the 1-D Fast Fourier Transform. */
void fft(fftw_complex *in, fftw_complex *out)
{
    // create a DFT plan
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    // execute the plan
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // clean up
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftw_cleanup();
}

/* Displays complex numbers in the form a +/- bi */
void displayComplex(fftw_complex *y)
{
    for (int idx = 0; idx < N; ++idx) {
        if (y[idx][IMAG] < 0) {
            std::cout << y[idx][REAL] << " - " << abs(y[idx][IMAG]) << "i" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << y[idx][REAL] << " + " << abs(y[idx][IMAG]) << "i" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

// Edit: Adjusted fftShift function per Ted's feedback
void fftShift(std::complex<double>* data) {
    static_assert(sizeof(fftw_complex) == sizeof(std::complex<double>));

    // even number of elements
    if(N % 2 == 0) {
        std::rotate(&data[0], &data[N >> 1], &data[N]);
    }
    // odd number of elements
    else {
        std::rotate(&data[0], &data[(N >> 1) + 1], &data[N]);
    }
}
// Edit: Accompanying fftShift to re-cast data
void fftShift(fftw_complex* data) {
    fftShift(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(data));
}

// Original (broken) FFT shift for complex data 
void fftShift(fftw_complex *data)
{
    // even number of elements
    if (N % 2 == 0) {
        std::rotate(&data[0], &data[N >> 1], &data[N]);
    }
    // odd number of elements
    else {
        std::rotate(&data[0], &data[(N >> 1) + 1], &data[N]);
    }
}

/* Test */
int main()
{
    // input array
    fftw_complex x[N];

    // output array
    fftw_complex y[N];

    // fill the first array with some numbers
    for (int idx = 0; idx < N; ++idx) {
        x[idx][REAL] = idx + 1;
        x[idx][IMAG] = 0;
    }
    
    // compute the FFT of x and store results in y
    fft(x, y);
    // display the results
    std::cout << "FFT =" << std::endl;
    displayComplex(y);

    // "shifted" results
    fftShift(y);
    std::cout << "\nFFT shifted =" << std::endl;
    displayComplex(y);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Didn't see any obvious existing questions that I could see applying to my case (could be wrong, I am still learning C++), so I made an account and this is my first question here. Feel free to provide feedback so that I can make my question easier to understand.

Comment: If you look at the video in detail, the author changes the function to `void fftShift(double *data)` it happens very quickly. I sort of works accidentally.

Comment: @alfC You are right - I didn't see that before. I wonder why though? It actually compiles without changing it. At least in VS2022.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, maybe VS2022 doesn't give the error for a function that is not used? is that what you are wondering about?

Comment: @alfC No, I wonder why they change to `double*` when `fftw_complex*` works in MSVC. Edit: Ah, wait... they have the other overload still there ... ok, got it. the `double*` overload is not used. :-)

Comment: It seems this question is about to be closed for lack of detail. I thought it became perfectly clear after the edit.

Comment: PSA, use `std::abs` not `abs`, otherwise it could be calling the integer version of `abs`. I get this with `-Wfatal-errors -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`

Comment: Do you want to use my library to simplify array manipulation and use of fftw? https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/fftw_so_example/include/multi/adaptors/fftw/test/so_shift.cpp

Comment: @alfC I'll take a look tomorrow at some point. Might use it for learning material.

Comment: @OzzlyOsborne, no problem, use this link, the above is broken: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/include/multi/adaptors/fftw/test/so_shift.cpp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex):

> For any object `z` of type `std::complex<T>`, `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` is the real part of `z` and `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` is the imaginary part of `z`.

> The intent of this requirement is to preserve binary compatibility between the C++ library complex number types and the C language complex number types (and arrays thereof), which have an identical object representation requirement.

Now, `fftw_complex` isn't necessarily a complex number type defined in the C language - but you will likely get away with doing a similar cast. In fact, the comment in the `fftw3.h` header suggests it will most probably be ok:

```
/* If <complex.h> is included, use the C99 complex type.  Otherwise
   define a type bit-compatible with C99 complex */
#if !defined(FFTW_NO_Complex) && defined(_Complex_I) && defined(complex) && defined(I)
#  define FFTW_DEFINE_COMPLEX(R, C) typedef R _Complex C
#else
#  define FFTW_DEFINE_COMPLEX(R, C) typedef R C[2]
#endif
```

<sup>The C++ definition of `fftw_complex` becomes `double[2]` which is also why `std::rotate` fails - you can't assign arrays to arrays.</sup>

So I'd define my function taking a `fftw_complex*` like this:

```cpp
void fftShift(std::complex<double>* data) {
    static_assert(sizeof(fftw_complex) == sizeof(std::complex<double>));

    // even number of elements
    if(N % 2 == 0) {
        std::rotate(&data[0], &data[N >> 1], &data[N]);
    }
    // odd number of elements
    else {
        std::rotate(&data[0], &data[(N >> 1) + 1], &data[N]);
    }
}

void fftShift(fftw_complex* data) {
    fftShift(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(data));
}

int main() {
    fftw_complex data[N];
    fftShift(data);
}
```

A nicer alternative would be to use `std::complex<double>`s in your C++ code and only cast to `fftw_complex*` when calling `fftw` functions.

```cpp
std::vector<std::complex<double>> wave;

fftw_function( reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(wave.data()), wave.size() );
```

---

> 1. How come this method worked in the tutorial video, but not for me?

It's because they use Visual Studio in the tutorial and the `std::rotate` implementation in that version of the standard library uses [`std::iter_swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) that is actually capable of swapping whole arrays. If `iter_swap` is mandated by the standard to be able to do that, I don't know, but `iter_swap` in the g++, clang++, icx and MSVC implementations are **all** capable of doing that. However, g++, clang++ and icx do not use their own `iter_swap`s in their `rotate` implementations - at least not in this case.

We can borrow a `rotate` implementation from [rotate @ cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) that actually uses `std::iter_swap` and then all four can `rotate` your `fftw_complex`s - using their own `iter_swap`s. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bb4da6333)

> 2. What are some ways to go about understanding what this error message means?

It means that `std::rotate` tries to assign a `double[2]` to another `double[2]`, *as-if* by doing:

```cpp
double a[2]{};
double b[2]{};
a = b;          // error: invalid array assignment
```

> 3. How can I implement a working `fftShift` function?

See above.

> 4. Is there a different compiler version I should be using?

No, even newer versions of `g++` and `clang++` would complain about the same issue. You could use Visual Studio or a different implementation of `rotate` (like the one on cppreference.com) - but I suggest just adapting and use `std::complex<double>`s that you cast to `fftw_complex`s when needed.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! Your suggested code worked for me (after adding #include <complex> at the top of my code block). Understanding the more complex data types and how to use them is still a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @OzzlyOsborne You're welcome! I had to dig in the Visual Studio library to find out why it actually worked in the tutorial. Explanation added to the answer.

Comment: I am confused. Even if iter_swap, or whatever, can swap the "arrays" directly, it wouldn't help here and give an erroneous result, because the actual data should be swapped (the two double elements at a time). There is no actual useful pointer to swap.

Comment: @alfC The actual data _is_ swapped so it does the right thing. However, the code I showed above and claimed didn't work in g++ and clang++ actually works in both [example](https://godbolt.org/z/MKoj9r963) so I'm not sure where my tired brain got that idea from Yesterday night. I'll remove those claims later when I get home.

Comment: Ok. But wait, now that I see your code from FFTW, I notice that if the type is defined as  `_Complex` (and not as `double[2]`) swap can work. (in other words, `_Complex` is a value type, `double[2]` is just an abomination (not a value).

Comment: @alfC Yes, that's what the comment under the fftw code block is aiming at too. The g++ and clang++ versions try to assign an array to another, which fails - but since both implementations have an `iter_swap` that is capable of actually swapping the values in the two arrays,  there seems to be something more going on. Right now I can't check but I suspect those implementations of `std::rotate` end up _not_ using `std::iter_swap` that would have made it work.

Comment: Yes, algorithms tend to use `iter_swap` which in turn one needs to end up customizing (although it is not technically allowed) to swap reference-like types. As I did many times.

Comment: @alfC Updated the answer to remove the erroneous claim about `iter_swap` not being capable in the g++ and clang++ implementations. It's fully capable - but they are not using it (at least not for this case) inside `rotate`. Replacing `rotate` with a version that actually uses the internal `iter_swap` makes all compilers happy.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, IMO, `fftw_complex` shouldn't be used at all, except when with reinterpret cast when calling fftw functions.

Comment: @alfC 100% agreement. That's why I suggested using `std::complex<double>`s in the C++ program and only do the cast to `fftw_complex*` when calling the `fftw` functions.